# my router not working with back / forward click

Tags: backbone.js

My router looks like this:

```
define(function(require) {
var _         = require('underscore'),
    Backbone  = require('backbone'),

    homeStageView,
    homeSidebarView,
    yxyStageView;



return Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '/web/:route'     : 'viewLoader'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        //this._bindRoutes();
        $('.link').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Backbone.history.navigate($(this).attr('href'), true);
        });
    },

    viewLoader: function(route) {
        switch(route) {
            case 'home': 
                this.homeHandler();
                break;
            case 'yxy':
                this.yxyHandler();
                break;
        }
    },

    // navigation handlers
    homeHandler: function() {
        if ( !homeStageView ) {
            require(['views/home-stage-view'], function(HomeStageView) {
                homeStageView = new HomeStageView();
                homeStageView.render();
            });    
        }
        else {
            homeStageView.render();
        }
        this.renderHomeSidebarView();
    },

    yxyHandler: function() {
        if ( !yxyStageView ) {
            require(['views/yxy-stage-view'], function(YxyStageView) {
                yxyStageView = new YxyStageView();
                yxyStageView.render();
            });    
        }
        else {
            yxyStageView.render();
        }
        this.renderHomeSidebarView();
    },

});
```

});

and in my main view I init the router like this:

```
appRouter = new AppRouter();    
if ( history && history.pushState ) {
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    console.log('has pushState');
}
else {
    Backbone.history.start();
    console.log('no pushState');
}
```

This works fine for loading all my views but it works not when user clicks the back forward button.

The url in the address bar chances accordingly but that's it. Obviously, I'm missing something.

Could someone please help out?

Answer (score 4):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-extend):

> **extend** `Backbone.Router.extend(properties, [classProperties])`
>
> [...] Note that you'll want to avoid using a leading slash in your route definitions:

Your route is `/web/:route` so try removing the leading slash:

```
routes: {
    'web/:route': 'viewLoader'
}
```